# How to get warnings on undefined CSS variables

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-variables, stylelint

Trying to use CSS variables for the first time. Doing it in a react (`create-react-app`) application, and works great. Only issue is that there's no warnings if I mistype a variable name or just simply forget to define it.

Is there a way to, for example, configure stylelint or scss to warn me when I have used a CSS variable that has not been set? Or a setting/extension in FireFox? Something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a suitable rule was added to [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/6361) (it might be behind an experimental flag, I have not tried to activate the rule yet).

The new rule is intended to supersede a [stylelint plugin](https://github.com/csstools/stylelint-value-no-unknown-custom-properties).

The interested reader can find a [discussion](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/2220) of the feature from 2016 (and a [dupe](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/2837) from 2017).